# Get data from Multiple tags BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get as much data as possible from this site including the title, time and the event per time.

For example for the Aniversary Awards Ceremony, it should print that title, 8:30, and the name of event that happens at 8:30.

The tags after the title, (such as the time) start to repeat/change multiple times not allowing to pull with accuracy. Is there a better way to approach this? Pull all data as accurate to the site?

Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
productlinks=[]

url='https://www.sitcancer.org/2020/program/annual-meeting-schedule-2020'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='HtmlContent')
for section in productlist:
    title=section.find('span',style="font-family: helvetica; color: #ef4136;")
    if title is not None:
        title=title.text
    else:
        title='No'
    print(title)
```

Comment: What is the question? Is there something specific that isn't working as you think it should?

Comment: The tags after the title, (such as the time) start to repeat/change multiple times not allowing to pull with accuracy. Is there a better way to approach this? Pull all data as accurate to the site?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close enough to what you need, and you can take from there:

```
from bs4 import Tag, NavigableString
tabs = soup.select('div.HtmlContent table[style="height: 740px; width: 100%;"] tbody')
for t in tabs[0]:    
    if not isinstance(t, NavigableString ) and len(t.text.strip())>0:        
        if 'Session' in t.text:
            print(t.text)
        else:
            if t.select_one('h3') is not None:
                print(t.text.strip())
            else:                
                for w in t.select('td span strong'):
                    print(w.text.strip())
                for f in t.select('span[style="color: #000000;"]'):
                    print(f.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
9 a.m.–3:15 p.m. EST* 
*Dates, times and program schedule subject to change. 


Immunotherapy Resistance and Failure


Session I: Defining Immune Checkpoint Inhibitor Resistance 


9 a.m.
Introduction

9:05 a.m.
Definitions of Resistance and Gaps in Current Understanding
Ryan J. Sullivan, MD - Massachusetts General Hospital
```

etc.